# Anonymous Recursive Function

Tags: powershell, function, recursion

Is it possible to create an anonymous Recursive Function in PowerShell? (if yes, how?)

I have a recursive object and using a recursive function to drill down through the properties, like:

```
$Object = ConvertFrom-Json '
{
    "Name" : "Level1",
    "Folder" : {
        "Name" : "Level2",
        "Folder" : {
            Name : "Level3"
        }       
    }
}'

Function GetPath($Object) {
    $Object.Name
    if ($Object.Folder) { GetPath $Object.Folder }
}

(GetPath($Object)) -Join '\'

Level1\Level2\Level3
```

The function is relative small and only required ones, therefore I would like to directly invoke it as an anonymous function, some like:

```
(&{
    $Object.Name
    if ($Object.Folder) { ???? $Object.Folder }
}) -Join '\'
```

Is this possible in PowerShell?
If yes, how can I (as clean as possible) refer to the current function at `????`?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, beat me to it lol

Comment: my answer was focusing on your main question but now I'm wondering why not consider use a `Queue` for this particular case ?

Comment: @Santiago, thanks for the answer (I was murdering around as I forgot to implement the `paran($s)` statement). Not sure if I understand "*consider use a Queue*"? Do you mean to keep the function flat (not recursive) and just *loop* though the child `folder` properties until it doesn't exist anymore? , I will actually consider that...

Comment: I've updated my answer using a `Queue`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not much documentation on this topic but you could execute the *anonymous script block* via [`$MyInvocation` automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#myinvocation), specifically it's [`ScriptInfo.ScriptBlock` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptinfo.scriptblock?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#system-management-automation-scriptinfo-scriptblock).

A simple example:

```bash
& {
    param([int] $i)

    if($i -eq 10) { return $i }
    ($i++)
    & $MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock $i
}

# Results in 0..10
```

Using your current code and Json provided in question:

```bash
(& {
    param($s)

    $s.Name; if ($s.Folder) { & $MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock $s.Folder }
} $Object) -join '\'

# Results in Level1\Level2\Level3
```

Same as the above but using [*pipeline processing*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.2#process) instead:

```bash
($Object | & {
    process {
        $_.Name; if($_.Folder) { $_.Folder | & $MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock }
    }
}) -join '\'
```

---

A bit more code but the same can be accomplished using a [`Collections.Queue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.queue?view=net-6.0) instead of recursion, which is likely to be more resource efficient:

```bash
$(
    $queue = [System.Collections.Queue]::new()
    $queue.Enqueue($object)
    while($queue.Count) {
        $node = $queue.Dequeue()
        $node.Name
        if($node.Folder) { $queue.Enqueue($node.Folder) }
    }
) -join '\'
```

Answer (score 2):

[**@Santiago**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon)'s helpful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72045538/1701026) was exactly where I was initially looking for.
Nevertheless, it doesn't always require a recursive function to crawl through a recursive object.
As in the [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I could just have done:

```
@(
    do {
        $Object.Name
        $Object = $Object.Folder
    } while ($Object)
) -Join '\'
```

Comment: definitely, I did over-complicate it didn't I 